# Field for publication status

Tags: database

I already browsed several posts but did not find an answer. I want to be able to make a list view that shows all my articles. Additionally the articles' teasers should show if the article has been published or not yet.

My Problem: The publication status doesnt exist as a field, so I cant add it to the lists' teasers. How can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance,

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Views has a field:

> Content: Published
>   Whether or not the content is published.

You should be able to add that to your Field based View to show the published status.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways of doing it:

1. In node.tpl.php file simply access `$node->status` property and output what you need if `$view_mode == 'teaser'`.
2. Use [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) to create a field that simply copies value of `$node->status` property, then use it as any other field.

Comment: Dear Molot, I did as suggested via computed field. Now it says "Undefined variable: node in eval() (line 1 of C:\inetpub\wwwroot\drupal\sites\all\modules\contrib\computed_field\computed_field.module(466) : eval()'d code).
•Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval() (line 1 of "

Comment: @user19044 I pointed them in order I'd use. And in computed field, try `$entity` instead. `dpr()` or `var_dump()` it to see what's inside. If still no luck, ask "how to use node status in computed field?" as new question and link that question here.